# After removing a child of a view and then readding it, the view will not display properly

Tags: java, android, android-view

I have created a view in which two views are included. Once a view as a waiting room (A) and in the second view (B), a call can be answered.

After a call has arrived at view A, the second view will be invoke (B). It works. If the user has finished the interaction he should get back to the view (A). Unfortunately that does not work.

Here is the code for invoke the view B. This works fine.

```
// Add view to content
OVSLobbyActivity.this.rootWaitingRoom.view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
OVSLobbyActivity.this.root.removeChild(OVSLobbyActivity.this.rootWaitingRoom);
OVSLobbyActivity.this.root.appendChild(OVSLobbyActivity.this.rootCallRoom);
OVSLobbyActivity.this.rootCallRoom.view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// Set fullscreen
OVSLobbyActivity.this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
OVSLobbyActivity.this.onWindowFocusChanged(true);

// force to change the layout
root.view.invalidate();
root.view.requestLayout();
```

Here is the code to hide the view B and show view A again. This does not work well. Here is the problem that only a white page will be shown. The elments inside the activity is missing.

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
this.onWindowFocusChanged(false);


this.rootCallRoom.view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
this.root.removeChild(OVSLobbyActivity.this.rootCallRoom);
this.root.appendChild(OVSLobbyActivity.this.rootWaitingRoom);
this.rootWaitingRoom.view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// force to change the layout
root.view.invalidate();
root.view.forceLayout();
root.view.requestLayout();
```

Do have any idea what is wrong?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that the size of the view has to be recalculated. After the measures recalculated you have to execute following line:

> this.view.requestLayout ();

After that the correct view will be shown.